# R kernel for Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install the IRkernel for jupyter notebook from devtools library on git_hub "https://irkernel.github.io/installation/", but get an error while installation. Here is what I am trying and the error that I get:

```
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

error:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. Installation failed: Command failed
>   (1)

I am not able to install the IRkernel from devtools, it returns the above error. Is there some problem with the R version? Can anyone please help?

Comment: I think you will need to pinpoint at what point of the above command do you get an error. Try commenting out the first line of code and install IRkernel, if it's successful then install the other packages. You're installing 9 packages in one execution so its hard to know which part of that program is throwing that error

Comment: > devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
Warning message:
GitHub repo contains submodules, may not function as expected! 
I am getting an error while installing IRkernel.

Comment: Thanks for that information, I've posted the explanation / fix as an answer below. Hope that's helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer of why it happened on a Windows system is that you have "C:\Program Files" and R didn't play well with that white space in between:

> This happens when both of the following conditions are met
>   - R is installed in a directory that contains whitespace in its name (e.g. "Program Files")
>   - Short filenames (SFN) are disabled for the volume on which R is installed

You can verify this by issuing the following command:

```
R.home()
```

The solution:

Try uninstalling and reinstalling R, this time into a brand-new directory tree (not under \Program Files).

This I understand is not the fault of the user, and there is an [ongoing issue thread on the package](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1514) but what I suggested above would be the quick fix you need.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using anaconda you can try this. Open the anaconda command prompt and type in

```
conda install -c r r-irkernel
```

source:
https://anaconda.org/r/r-irkernel